# How to work with DrawingVisual classes in WinUI 3?

Tags: .net, canvas, uwp, winui-3

So, the learning resources for .NET WinUI 3 are very scarce. In WPF, we used a `UIElement` with `DrawingVisual` children that could be added to a `Canvas`. How is this, if possible, done in WinUI 3? If this is not possible, what are the most lightweight drawing elements in WinUI 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone with similar question:

The Microsoft.UI.Composition libraries are the key. Here are some very nice tutorials to get started:

https://xamlbrewer.wordpress.com/2018/08/13/drawing-shapes-with-windows-composition-in-uwp/
https://xamlbrewer.wordpress.com/2016/01/04/using-the-composition-api-in-uwp-apps/

Basically you have to compose a shape hierarchy bottom up from (Example) CompositionRoundedRectangleGeometry to CompositionSpriteShape to ShapeVisual. Then add this ShapeVisual to the Canvas ContainerVisual.